# android: error al intentar usar java 8

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Estoy intentando subir la versión de java (a java 8), en mi `build.gradle(Module:app)` agregué lo siguiente:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.2" 
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxx.xxx.xxx.xx"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        jackOptions {
            enabled true
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        encoding "UTF-8"
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    compile project(path: ':slide')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Pero al intentar ejecutar el *app* me aparece ***"Gradle Build Runing"*** y no pasa de ahí.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿A que se debe esta situación?

Comment: @devav Creo que no es necesario esto, que versión de Android Studio usas? agrega todo el build.gradle por favor!

Comment: Que parte agregaste en el build.gradle?

Comment: Hola, ¿sabes si tu red tiene proxy?

Comment: Yo cuando lo probé, tuve que subir el minSdkVersion a 24, si quieres usar las sintaxis lambda recomiendan usar retrolambda compatible con java 1.7 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23318109/is-it-possible-to-use-java-8-for-android-development

Comment: yo no le encuentro el sentido, es decir, hasta dentro de 10 años que android N sea la api mas antigua en el mercado no podreos usar java 8? xD

Answer (score 1):

No es posible usar Java 8 de manera normal pues se requiere otro compilador que traduzca a versión 7 debido a que es el nivel de soporte acutal. El compilador se llama Jack y lo puedes encontrar [aquí](https://source.android.com/source/jack.html). Una vez instalado y configurado, en el build.gradle del módulo incluye:

```
android {
  ...
  defaultConfig {
    ...
    jackOptions {
      enabled true
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

Si lo único que necesitas son expresiones lambda, puedes recurrir a [Retrolambda](https://github.com/evant/gradle-retrolambda)

Comment: Dos downvotes, sin comentarios, y sin otra solución propuesta. Tenemos gente que sabe más que los propios desarrolladores: https://developer.android.com/guide/platform/j8-jack.html?hl=es

Answer (score 0):

Si cambias de versión a java 8 no debes tener problema en Android Studio usando como minimo la versión 2.1, unicamente asegura usar una versión de Android Build Tools 24 o posterior, lo mismo para targetSdkVersion en tu proyecto debe ser configurado a 24 .

Si tu Androis Studio no continua, trata esta opcion, lo que realiza es que no descarga las dependencias,  pudiera ser que por alguna razon no las puede descargar.

En el menu ve a : 
`File` -> `Settings` -> `Build, Execution, Deployment` -> `Build Tools` -> `Gradle`.

Selecciona la opcion: 'Offline work'

[image: check this to reduce build time]